# Find all tables of a linked server using server provider IBMDASQL from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, db2, openquery

I have some linked servers which, when I make the statement,

```
exec sp_linkedservers
```

in SQL server shows up as:

```
SRV_NAME      SRV_PROVIDERNAME         SRV_CAT
SERVER1       IBMDASQL                 INICAT1
SERVER2       IBMDASQL                 INICAT1
```

I've been able to access another linked server with the same provider name using:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SERVER3,'SELECT * FROM INICAT1.Schema3.Table')
```

I don't know the specifics of the two other servers, only that they have the same value on `SRV_CAT`.

Does anyone know how one can find table information from a server using `IBMDASQL` as serverprovider?

What I've tried is to use the "regular" ways of finding the information, i.e. for instance using:

```
exec sp_tables_ex SERVER1
```

but this only shows an empty result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `openquery()` one can use:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED_SRV,
'SELECT * FROM SYSTEM.TABLES WHERE Table_Schema LIKE ''TableofInterest''
 order by Table_Name')
```